# Python code not continuing after while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm a beginner in using python so this might be a stupid question.
I'm trying to make a login program to practice what I've learnt so far but python just wouldn't continue reading the rest of my code after the while condition is met here's my code incase you don't understand what I mean

```
def register():
    confirm_user = ""
    username_reg = ""
    pass_enter = ""
    pass_confirm = ""
    
    while confirm_user == "yes":
        username_reg = input("Please enter a username you would like to use: ")
        confirm_user = input("Would you like to confirm this username?: ")
    if confirm_user == "yes":
        username_enter = open("username.py", 'w')
        username_enter.write(username_reg)

        raise Exception("Username created successfully!")


    elif confirm_user == "no":
        print("Choose a different username")
    else:
        print("Invalid input please enter yes or no")
    while pass_enter != pass_confirm:
        pass_enter = input("Please enter a password you would like to use: ")
        pass_confirm = input("Please confirm password by re-typing it: ")
    if pass_enter == pass_confirm:
        password_enter = open("password.py", 'w')
        password_enter.write(pass_enter)
    elif pass_enter != pass_confirm:
            print("Passwords do not match please re-enter password and re-confirm")


def login():
    pass_log = ""
    user_log = ""
    pass_check = open("password.py", 'r')
    user_check = open("username.py", 'r')
    while user_log != user_check.readline():
        user_log = input("Please enter your username: ")
        if user_log != user_check.readline():
            print("This username does not exist, please enter a valid username")
        elif user_log == user_check.readline():
            while pass_log != pass_check.readline():
                pass_log = input("Please enter your password: ")
                if pass_log != pass_check.readline():
                    print("This password is incorrect, please re-enter your password")
                elif pass_log == pass_check.readline():
                    print("Welcome back " + user_check.readline())


intro = input("Welcome, to login type 'login' to register a new account type 'register': ")
if intro == "register":
    register()
elif intro == "login":
    login()
```

after entering 'register' and entering the username and saying 'yes' to confirm the program just stops and doesn't continue the rest of the register() function and I have no idea why...

Comment: Did you mean that to be "not equal"? `while confirm_user != "yes":`. Right now, the program will continue only if the user doesn't say "yes".

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop? The input is handled outside the loop...

Comment: `confirm_user` is initialized to a blank string, so the `while confirm_user == "yes"` loop will never execute.  Similarly, `pass_enter` and `pass_confirm` are initialized to blank strings, so the `while pass_enter != pass_confirm` loop will never execute.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  You posted about 50 lines of code for a 5-line problem, and your example requires us to enter testing input.

Comment: @JohnGordon so should I remove the blank strings? I just tried that and still have the same problem

Comment: @tdelaney yes i mean that to be 'not equal' I tried == no and == yes, when I put == "no" the program doesn't even start

Comment: @Prune here's what happens when I run the code:

Welcome, to login type 'login' to register a new account type 'register': register
Please enter a username you would like to use: John123
Would you like to confirm this username?: yes
Username created successfully!
>>> 
The program just stops there and does not ask me for the password

Comment: If confirm_user == "yes", then you raise an exception.  Of course the program stops!  What did you expect to happen after raising an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes.

1. The first While-Loop will never be entered because

> confirm_user = ""

at the beginning and we are only starting the while-Loop if

> confirm_user = "Yes"

I changed that to a bool which state is changed in the while-loop, when

> confirm_user == "Yes"

2. The File should be closed after writing and the "w" should be changed to "a" so the new user is appended and the file is not overwriten
3. The line following will kill the programm because we say an exception accured.

> raise Exception("Username created successfully!")

4. In the second while-Loop we have the same problem we had in the first one
5. Same with the writing to the Password file

```
def register():
    confirm_user = ""
    confirmed = False
    username_reg = ""
    pass_enter = ""
    pass_confirm = ""
    same = False
    
    while confirmed == False:
        username_reg = input("Please enter a username you would like to use: ")
        confirm_user = input("Would you like to confirm this username?: ")
        if confirm_user.lower() == "yes":
            confirmed = True
    
    username_enter = open("username.txt", 'a')
    username_enter.write(username_reg)
    username_enter.close()
    print("Username created successfully!")

    while same == False:
        pass_enter = input("Please enter a password you would like to use: ")
        pass_confirm = input("Please confirm password by re-typing it: ")
        if pass_enter == pass_confirm:
            same = True
        else:
            print("Passwords do not match please re-enter password and re-confirm")
    
    password_enter = open("password.txt", 'a')
    password_enter.write(pass_enter)
    password_enter.close()

def login():
    pass_log = ""
    user_log = ""
    pass_check = open("password.py", 'r')
    user_check = open("username.py", 'r')
    while user_log != user_check.readline():
        user_log = input("Please enter your username: ")
        if user_log != user_check.readline():
            print("This username does not exist, please enter a valid username")
        elif user_log == user_check.readline():
            while pass_log != pass_check.readline():
                pass_log = input("Please enter your password: ")
                if pass_log != pass_check.readline():
                    print("This password is incorrect, please re-enter your password")
                elif pass_log == pass_check.readline():
                    print("Welcome back " + user_check.readline())


intro = input("Welcome, to login type 'login' to register a new account type 'register': ")
if intro == "register":
    register()
elif intro == "login":
    login()
```

Comment: Have you closed the file?

Comment: And the second while-loop doesn't start because they are the same at the begining both are " "

Comment: problem is when I remove the " " it asks me to define the variable so idk what to do

Comment: added a username_enter.close() right enter the username_enter.write still getting the same problem

Comment: im trying not to be a pain in the ass and I really appreciate the help but now I copied your code word for word but after I enter a username and say "Yes" to confirm it keeps asking me to enter the username again

Comment: Did you write Yes the way it's written in  the programm?
If you want it to work without case sensetivity change confirm_user == "Yes" to confirm_user.lower() == "yes":

Comment: Yes i did I double checked aswell

Comment: just added break under the if statement after using your boolean method and it worked, thank you very much for your time